# Using a BinaryWriter for partial file updates

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm looking for a method by which I can do partial updates, adding and removing key/value pairs to a file from my dictionary using `BinaryWriter`. Overwriting a complete file seems simple enough with the following code but since I could potentially have a lot of records, ~26,000, I'm worried that performance would become an issue. (I have not run tests to confirm this).

The context in which I need this is for a persistable index of cached image files accessed via a `HttpModule`.

My starting point:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(this.cachedIndexFile))
{
    using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
    {
        // Put the count.
        binaryWriter.Write(this.Count);

        // Put the values.
        foreach (var pair in this)
        {
            binaryWriter.Write(pair.Key);
            binaryWriter.Write(pair.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

If there are better alternatives within the framework I would happily use them. `BinaryWriter` is the only thing I know of and searching alternatives has proved unrewarding.

I have found this article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17716/Insert-Text-into-Existing-Files-in-C-Without-Temp) but have found it difficult to follow and the downloadable project file even more difficult. Perhaps a solution could be based upon that?

Comment: Partial updates pretty much requires fixed-size fields. Do you have a maximum key/value size? Could you just use a database instead? How often do you need to replace the file? You should *absolutely* test this before worrying about it.

Comment: You could create a sort of in-file directory structure which controls the number, position and size of blocks of fixed size and use this information to write to these blocks as required (kind of the good old `Structured Storage`). However, I'd also recommend to use a database... which does not mean a big fat thing nowadays...

Comment: A good little database can be SQLite.

Comment: Considering that you can easily write 50 MB per second on today's hardware, I doubt that writing 26,000 key/value pairs is going to take much time. If you have to do a lot of updates, though, a light database as others have suggested would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks folks, I did some testing yesterday and yeah... It is too slow for what I need. I'me going to use a db. I've been looking at SQLite but the documentation is pretty outdated. I should figure it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice in comments I decided that indeed a database was the best idea. I have gone with SQLite.